# zsh: no such file or directory. What should I do?

Tags: git, github, zsh

I am a new user of a MacBook M1 today, and I wanted to clone this repository in my terminal. I got this error:

```sh
Last login: Thu May 27 15:05:24 on ttys000

sabuz@Sabuzs-MacBook-Pro ~ % https://github.com/ProgrammingHero1/complete-web-de
velopment-bangla-resources.git

zsh: no such file or directory: https://github.com/ProgrammingHero1/complete-web
-development-bangla-resources.git

sabuz@Sabuzs-MacBook-Pro ~ % _
```

The repository link is `https://github.com/ProgrammingHero1/complete-web-development-bangla-resources.git`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You are using an URL as if it were a command!!! What would you expect poor zsh to do with it? For cloning a repository, use the `git` command.  See `git clone -h`.

Answer (score 3):

```sh
sabuz@Sabuzs-MacBook-Pro ~ % https://blah.blah.blah.git
```

Assuming everything up to the `~ %` is your prompt (and it almost certainly *is,* based on that last line with the cursor), you're trying to *run* a `git` file in the context of the shell. You probably just copied the link of the github page and pasted that into your terminal as-is.

If you want to get the files, you need to *clone* it, as in :

```sh
sabuz@Sabuzs-MacBook-Pro ~ % git clone https://blah.blah.blah.git
                             ^^^^^^^^^^
                              add this
```